# How to filter data from object on click of an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am retrieving data from an object called emp. I am looping through the the object and printing each entry in a row.

I want to let user be able to filter their data if they tick a checkbox. E.G. if they click the checkbox only employees younger than 33 are shown.

My code so far:

```
   var emp = {
"employees":[
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "details": {
            "role" : "manager",
            "age" : 55
        },
        "lastName":"Doe"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Anna",
        "details": {
            "role" : "cashier",
            "age" : 35
        },
        "lastName":"Smith"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Peter",
        "details": {
            "role" : "manager",
            "age" : 23
        },
        "lastName":"Jones"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Jim",
        "details": {
            "role" : "cleaner",
            "age" : 20
        },
        "lastName":"Doveson"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Nick",
        "details": {
            "role" : "waiter",
            "age" : 38
        },
        "lastName":"Doe"
    }
]
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var fixtureHTML = "";
 $.each(emp.employees, function(key, value) { 
            fixtureHTML += '<div class="media">'
            fixtureHTML += '<div class="meta-info">';
            fixtureHTML +=  '<span class="info">' + value.firstName + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="info">' + value.lastName + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="role">' + value.details.role + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="age">' + value.details.age+ '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '</div></div>';

            if($("#check").is(':checked')) {
                if(value.details.age < 33) {
                   return false;
                }
            }
});
$('.js-load').append(fixtureHTML);
});

<div class="js-load"></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="check-filter" value="unit-in-group" id="check"/>
Check this box for filter by employees younger than 30
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is the best way but this could give you an idea

```js
var emp = {
"employees":[
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "details": {
            "role" : "manager",
            "age" : 55
        },
        "lastName":"Doe"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Anna",
        "details": {
            "role" : "cashier",
            "age" : 35
        },
        "lastName":"Smith"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Peter",
        "details": {
            "role" : "manager",
            "age" : 23
        },
        "lastName":"Jones"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Jim",
        "details": {
            "role" : "cleaner",
            "age" : 20
        },
        "lastName":"Doveson"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Nick",
        "details": {
            "role" : "waiter",
            "age" : 38
        },
        "lastName":"Doe"
    }
]
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var fixtureHTML = "";
 $.each(emp.employees, function(key, value) { 
            fixtureHTML += '<div class="media">'
            fixtureHTML += '<div class="meta-info">';
            fixtureHTML +=  '<span class="info">' + value.firstName + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="info">' + value.lastName + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="role">' + value.details.role + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="age">' + value.details.age+ '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '</div></div>';
});
$('.js-load').append(fixtureHTML);
});

$("#check").on("change",function(){
  var check = $(this);
  $('.js-load').html("");
  var fixtureHTML = "";
  $.each(emp.employees, function(key, value) { 
  if(check.is(':checked')) {
                if(value.details.age < 33) {
                  fixtureHTML += '<div class="media">'
            fixtureHTML += '<div class="meta-info">';
            fixtureHTML +=  '<span class="info">' + value.firstName + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="info">' + value.lastName + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="role">' + value.details.role + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="age">' + value.details.age+ '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '</div></div>';
                }
            } else{
             
            fixtureHTML += '<div class="media">'
            fixtureHTML += '<div class="meta-info">';
            fixtureHTML +=  '<span class="info">' + value.firstName + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="info">' + value.lastName + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="role">' + value.details.role + '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '<span class="age">' + value.details.age+ '</span>';
            fixtureHTML += '</div></div>';
              }
    });
  $('.js-load').append(fixtureHTML);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-load"></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="check-filter" value="unit-in-group" id="check"/>
Check this box for filter by employees younger than 30
```

Answer (score 1):

The important part is the following handler:

```
$('#check').on('change', function() {    
  var $media = $('.media');

  // reduce selected set of .media nodes to those that have an .age >= 33
  // and toggle their visibility based on #check's `checked` property
  $media.filter(function(i, el) {
    return parseInt($(el).find('.age').text(), 10) >= 33;
  }).toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

Refer to jQuery's [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) functions as well as [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
var emp = {
  "employees":[
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "details": {
            "role" : "manager",
            "age" : 55
        },
        "lastName":"Doe"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Anna",
        "details": {
            "role" : "cashier",
            "age" : 35
        },
        "lastName":"Smith"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Peter",
        "details": {
            "role" : "manager",
            "age" : 23
        },
        "lastName":"Jones"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Jim",
        "details": {
            "role" : "cleaner",
            "age" : 20
        },
        "lastName":"Doveson"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Nick",
        "details": {
            "role" : "waiter",
            "age" : 38
        },
        "lastName":"Doe"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var fixtureHTML = "";
  
  $.each(emp.employees, function(key, value) { 
    fixtureHTML += '<div class="media">'
    fixtureHTML += '<div class="meta-info">';
    fixtureHTML +=  '<span class="info">' + value.firstName + '</span>';
    fixtureHTML += '<span class="info">' + value.lastName + '</span>';
    fixtureHTML += '<span class="role">' + value.details.role + '</span>';
    fixtureHTML += '<span class="age">' + value.details.age+ '</span>';
    fixtureHTML += '</div></div>';
  });
  
  $('.js-load').append(fixtureHTML);
  
  $('#check').on('change', function() {    
    var $media = $('.media');
    
    $media.filter(function(i, el) {
      return parseInt($(el).find('.age').text(), 10) >= 33;
    }).toggle(!this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-load"></div>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-filter" value="unit-in-group" id="check"/>
  Check this box for filter by employees younger than 30
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create function `checkStatus` and add code for filtration in it:

Call this function as use click on checkbox for filtration purpose

```js
var emp = {
"employees":[
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "details": {
            "role" : "manager",
            "age" : 55
        },
        "lastName":"Doe"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Anna",
        "details": {
            "role" : "cashier",
            "age" : 35
        },
        "lastName":"Smith"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Peter",
        "details": {
            "role" : "manager",
            "age" : 23
        },
        "lastName":"Jones"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Jim",
        "details": {
            "role" : "cleaner",
            "age" : 20
        },
        "lastName":"Doveson"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"Nick",
        "details": {
            "role" : "waiter",
            "age" : 38
        },
        "lastName":"Doe"
    }
]
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkStatus();
});
function checkStatus() {  
  var fixtureHTML = "";
  $.each(emp.employees, function(key, value) { 

      if($("#check").is(':checked')) {
          if(value.details.age < 33) {
             return false;
          }
      }
      fixtureHTML += '<div class="media">'
      fixtureHTML += '<div class="meta-info">';
      fixtureHTML +=  '<span class="info">' + value.firstName + '</span>';
      fixtureHTML += '<span class="info">' + value.lastName + '</span>';
      fixtureHTML += '<span class="role">' + value.details.role + '</span>';
      fixtureHTML += '<span class="age">' + value.details.age+ '</span>';
      fixtureHTML += '</div></div>';

      
  });
  $('.js-load').html(fixtureHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-load"></div>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkStatus();" name="check-filter" value="unit-in-group" id="check"/>
```

Comment: "[...] only employees younger than 33 are shown" This solution does not result in the desired outcome.

Comment: Recreating the DOM every time the checkbox is invoked is also an extremely poor practice for something as simple as toggling visibility...